# Xcode 9.2 Asset Catalog editor pane empty

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, xcasset

Whenever I try to add a new resource or edit an existing resource in my Asset Catalog in Xcode 9.2, the editor pane is just totally empty. I have tried App Icon Set, Color Set, Image Set, and I get the same result every time. I have tried quitting Xcode and deleting Derived Data. I have no warnings or errors in my issue navigator. My build succeeds.

[image: Screenshot of the issue.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select Image Set and click on Show Overview like below image.

[image]

Comment: Meant to leave a comment but clicked the wrong box. I'm not able to accept the answer yet. I will when I can.

Comment: There's a timer before you're allowed.